# Windows File Explorer - Only first 20 char shown while hovering over taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

When I hover over File Explorer in the taskbar, I'm shown the first characters of the folder names. However, this is almost useless when I have multiple folders open in the same parent folder. For example, the picture below shows 5/7 of the folder names as "C:\Users\marca\Google Driv...".

[image: Hovering over File Explorer in taskbar.]

Is there any way to make File Explorer show the end of the folder path instead of the beginning?

Comment: What OS and version are your running looks like windows 10. Do you know if its the anniversary edition? On my windows 10 anniversary edition install I just see the folder names as you wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I'm using Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393). I freshly installed it last week. I just found the solution to my problem, which I'm posting as an answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: @CanProgram Not a solution to your question, but I think you might appreciate [Clover](http://ejie.me/). It makes Windows Explorer have tabs like Google Chrome.

Comment: @Vinayak, that's the first I've heard of it, and it looks useful! I just installed it (I don't understand Chinese, so I had to guess that the second checkbox was for installing bloatware, so I unchecked that).

It seems pretty straightforward. I think I'm going to really like this! I love that I can just middle mouse click on folders like I'm used to in my browser! I wish I had the option of having more than one window though, as I often like having 2-4 folders visible at once for transferring files. If I could do that, I think this would be a perfect tool. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: [Download Clover 3 here](http://ejie.me/#)


Cheatsheet:
Ctrl + T to open the page
Ctrl + W to close the page
Ctrl + Tab to switch pages
Double click on empty space to go up a level

Comment: @CanProgram You can already do that. I am using an older version of Clover (3.0.406.0) and if the developer hasn't changed it for newer versions, you should be able to drag out a 'tab' into a separate window just like you'd do in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Windows last week and although I'm grateful computer is usable again, I lost my previous settings. I discovered how to alter this, which I describe below.

*This solution may be considered suboptimal, as it alters how the folder path appears for all Explorer windows instead of only affecting how it appears while hovering over the taskbar icon.*

*(Note that the breadcrumbs in the address bar are still shown, so you can still see the location there.)*

1. Access Folder Options
2. Click on the View tab
3. Uncheck "Display the full path in the title bar"

[How to access Explorer properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNyer.png)

[Which Explorer property you need to set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8nXe.png)